# Magento 2 - Data migration tools and new products migrate from Magento1

Tags: magento2, products, migration, delta-migration

A month ago I created a new website with Magento 2 and I used the data migration tools to migrate the old website from Magento 1.

Since then the old Magento1 website has added new products to the store and now I need to insert these new products into my new Magento 2 store, plus I need to update the already existing products.

Data migration tools don't let me do that, I've tried exporting/importing from Magento 1 and Magento 2 core but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to do migrate product from Magento1 to Magento2?

Any advice, please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed your requirement. And I am sure this is not possible with existing Migrated Magento. You need to do a new migration.

You'll do Delta migration but it only inserts new orders and customers not products and other data.

Note: If you have migrated M2 with live M1 website database then do delta with the same m1 database then it'll possible otherwise it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a reliable Magento migration expert to help you to migrate all your data from Magento 1 to Magento 2 with a high level of security and accuracy.

As you may know, there are a lot of conflicts and differences between the structures of those 2 versions so you need to be careful during the migration process!